# Yup validation schema for radio buttons with write-in option

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I've created a component in my form that is a multiple choice field with a write-in option and trying to write a Yup validation schema that captures the behavior that I want and I'm having some trouble with it.

[image]

The user must pick one and only one option. If the user picks the last radio button (let's call it the "Other" radio button), the text field, which initially is disabled, becomes enabled and allows for typing. They must type in something between 5 and 20 characters.

So far, I have something like:

```
{
    regularOption: yup.string()
    otherRadio: yup.boolean()
    otherText: yup.string()
       .min(5, "Please enter at least 5 characters)
       .max(20, "Your input must not exceed 20 characters)
}
```

But I'm stuck on how to get cross-field behavior: that if a regular option is selected, then the `otherRadio` should be false and `otherText` should be empty. And if the `otherRadio` is selected, then the `regularOption` should be empty and the `otherText`s should have between 5 and 20 characters inclusive. I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Schema.when(keys: string | string[], builder: object | (values: any[], schema) => Schema): Schema`

App.js

```
export const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <div clasName="radioGroup">
        <label>
            Loyalty
            <input type="radio" name="important_trait" value={'loyalty'}/>
        </label>
        <label>
            Communication
            <input type="radio" name="important_trait" value={'communication'}/>
        </label>
        <label>
            Trust
            <input type="radio" name="important_trait" value={'trust'}/>
        </label>
        <label>
            Other
            <input type="radio" name="important_trait" value={'other'}/>
        </label>

        {/* If important_trait == other */}

        <input type="text" name="other_important_trait" />
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Yup Schema

```
{
    important_trait: yup.string().required()
    other_important_trait:  Yup.string().when('important_trait', {
      is: 'other',
      then: Yup.string().required('Please enter at least 5 characters')
    })
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jquense/yup#schemawhenkeys-string--string-builder-object--values-any-schema--schema-schema